# How to show hours and minutes on the DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using C# .NET and I have a Windows Form with a DateTimePicker.

My question is: how can I display the hours and the minutes (for the user to change) along with the year, month, and day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the CustomFormat property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

It allows you to set the format however you'd like.  Also, to make it apply, you'll have to set the DatetimePicker.Format to Custom.

EDIT: If you provide a better idea/example of the format you want displayed, I can help with the actual format string.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Format` property to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` and set the [`CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) property to a format that includes the time.

Answer (score 0):

See here for all DateTimePicker properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker_properties.aspx

The Format property will let you set a format string to include hours, minutes, seconds.

Edit:

Here are predefined formats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepickerformat.aspx

As the other poster mentioned, you can set your own format in the CustomFormat property.